# install only js file for dependencies

Tags: javascript, bower

I have a bower.json file as following :

```
{
  "name": "dst-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "highcharts-ng": "~0.0.11",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "ignore": [
        "source",
        "src",
        "spec",
        ".bowerrc",
        ".gitignore",
        ".jshintignore",
        ".jshintrc",
        "bower.json",
        "gruntfile.js",
        "package.json",
        "README.md"
    ],
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "dstAngularApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
```

when I run `bower update` I'll get in angular folder the `src` folder, and in boostrap folder the `js`, `less`, `nuget` ... folders with the whole bunch of files that make up all of me dependencies :

[image]

How could I install only js files without including all these folders and files ?

Answer (score 0):

The ignore section specifies what your package wants to ignore when you publish it, so doing it this way won't work.

A fix could be making a bash script that rm's all these files once it's been installed. This file could be then put into the postinstall section of your bower.json.